# Java RMI Unmarshall Exception

Tags: java, serialization, rmi

I'm calling this remote method:

```
RespuestaError<Co>  cox(String a, String b, String c, int d) throws RemoteException;
```

I'm getting this error

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: jtwitter.base.RespuestaError
```

It's saying that RespuestaError is not Serializable but it is:

```
public class RespuestaError<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8483079015565009698L;

    private T returned;
    private Error error;

    public RespuestaError(T returned, Error error)
    {
      //...
    }

     //...
}
```

Where `Error` is a enum.
In this particular case `T` is:

```
public class Co implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2759254657635643074L;

    private String  a;
    private int     b;
    private Us  c;

    public Co(String a, int b, Us c)
    {
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

And the Us class is:

```
public class Us implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6725570673833522155L;

    private int a;
    private String b; 
    private String c;
    private String d;
    private String e;
    private int    f;

    public Us(int a, String b, String c, String d, String e, int f)
    {
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

Everithing extends Serializable I don't see the error.

Comment: I believe that ether the `private T returned` and 
    `private Error error` should be `implements Serializable` as well.

Comment: I happened to just complete an RMI program, and I just tried much similar with what you do, and I do not see any error. Perhaps you make sure all files are re-compiled, and make sure you import java.io.Serializable ?

Comment: @Gordon Liang I'm afraid you are right. A public no-arg constructor is not needed. It was my mistake I misinterpreted the documentation. Thanks.

Comment: @Little Sanit Welcome. I also suspected that at the beginning. But it turns out not like that.  There is a specification which is more clear: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/input.html

Comment: @Gordon Liang You know I've been believing for years that constructor was required?? A curse on serialization! ;-) And thanks for the link.

Comment: You're not running the code you think you're running. Clean, build, deploy, retest.

Comment: @EJP Now i get java.lang.Exception

Comment: @jmb95 post the stack here!

Comment: @EJP problem fixed, THANKS !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no error in the code. The problem is that I'm not running the code that i'm thinking im running. Cleaning and Re-compiling all files solves this problem.